# Why Does my Python Multiprocessing Process Subclass Return as None When Instantiated?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

my goal is to create a subclass of multiprocessing.Process to execute tasks based on instructions that are fed into a multiprocessing.Queue as objects and after the task is completed, set a task attribute to indicate the success of the process and pass the task-object to another queue handling responses. Later I plan to instantiate this custom class multiple times to have the different tasks completed faster.

My code is as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

# Define task-object that should be passed through queues
class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, task_type, detail=None, error=None):
        self.type = task_type
        self.detail = detail
        self.error = error

# Define how to handle a task - simulating for now, to see that everything is passed around properly
def handle_task(task):
    if task.type == 'UPDATE':
        task.detail = 'updating data'
    elif task.type == 'ACTUALIZE':
        task.detail = 'actualizing knowledge'
    else:
        task.detail = 'UNKNOWN TASK TYPE'
        task.error = True
    # if no errors by now, assume success
    if task.error == None:
        task.error = False
    return task

# Define worker process that executes task handling
class Task_handler(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, task_queue, response_queue):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.response_queue = response_queue
        self.keep_going = True

    def run(self):
        while self.keep_going:
            task = self.task_queue.get()
            if task.type == 'TERMINATE':
                self.keep_going = False
                self.detail = self.name
                self.error = False
            elif task.type == 'STATUS':
                task.detail = self.name
                task.error = False
            else:
                task = handle_task(task)
            self.response_queue.put(task)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    task_queue = mp.Queue()
    response_queue = mp.Queue()
    t = Task_handler(task_queue, response_queue)
    t.start()
    task_queue.put(Task('STATUS'))
    task_queue.put(Task('TERMINATE'))
    t.join()
    while not response_queue.empty():
        task = response_queue.get()
        print('{} {}, error {}'.format(task.type, task.detail, task.error))
```

When I run my code in python 3.7.3 on windows 10 it runs fine, but when I run it in python 3.6.9 in linux it gets stuck and I don't understand why this is the case. Also I would appreciate hints on how to do this most efficiently, as I have received no formal training in programming and likely am not aware of all the "dos and don'ts".
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like `t` takes the return from `start()`, which I assume returns `None`. Did you mean to examine `response_queue`?

Comment: `t = (...).start()` is not the same as `t = ...; t.start()`.

Comment: thank you very much! This solved me getting the proper return and I updated my code to match the change! Howeverm I still wonder why my tasks that I pass are not moved from the task_queue to the response_queue?

Comment: I expect that you should be adding a number of `Task` instances, followed by a `Task('TERMINATE')`. Then you should do `t.join()`. Then you can examine the `response_queue`.

Comment: @quamrana, thank you for the suggestion. After i run t.join() my code simply hangs and does not return anything. Would you have any idea why it does so? I seems like no tasks are being moved between queues either.

Comment: I get errors with the code you have posted. Please post your *real* code.

Comment: @quamrana - I realized I had forgotten an ' after in '__main__:. I corrected it now and thank you for trying to figure out what goes wrong. I really appreciate it! :-)

Comment: And the import time. All I did was to remove ‘self.terminate()’, added t.join() and print(response_queue)

Comment: Your prose hasn't been updated to keep pace with changes to the code -- the English-language text states a bug that you fixed in Revision 2. Please be sure you keep them in sync; if it takes time to edit things properly, you can delete the question, edit while it's deleted, and undelete it when you've got it fixed up and internally consistent.

Comment: @quamrana I have tried running this on python3.7 on windows now, where it runs as expected. However, when I try to run it in linux (wher i originally inteded to run the code) it seems to get stuck, would you happen to know what that happens?

Comment: I’m running on windows also and it works for me.